# How can I delete my history in Pandora?

Tags: pandora

I made all these stations over the years, and they are all mixed up and messed up, I want to start over from scratch.

How can I delete my history in Pandora?

Answer (score 1):

Mouse over the station name and an arrow will appear to the right of the station name.  Click the arrow and you will be given a menu which includes the option for deleting a station.

[image]

Once you click delete, it will automatically delete the station.  It will allow you to undelete the station immediately, but once you dismiss that or move on to something else, you will not be able to undelete anything (so make sure you really wanted that one deleted).

Answer (score 0):

When you were going to search for something and you click on something that you didn't mean to how do you delete it so no one else sees it or if when someone gets on your phone they don't see. It's sort of like when you go and do you want to look for a song and you get it and you play for like the premium 30 minutes.